# NodeJS Error: Can't Find Variable: require

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, npm

I am working with a NodeJS server that hosts a website and a Javascript program. Most of the javascript works fine, but I am running into an error now with one of the npm modules that isn't able to be "required".

I'm getting an error from the inspector console that:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require
```

I am not sure what's happening here, as from what I can tell the server should have access to these public modules. Here is the server code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {

    if(request.url === "/Users/christophermartone/Desktop/Programing/resturauntApp/driver.js") {
        var file = fs.createReadStream('driver.js');
        file.pipe(response);
        console.log("Made it to JS");
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javascript'});
    } 
    else {
        var file = fs.createReadStream('index.V1.0.html');
        console.log("Made it to HTML");
        file.pipe(response);
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    }
}).listen(8080);
```

I found some documentation that suggested I should do npm link @Source/Module... which I did, but the issue is still not resolved. 
Am I missing something in the server script? Or is there an extra step I am missing? 
I can provide the full html and javascript code if needed, but the issue does not appear to be with them, only when they are running on the Node server.

Comment: What command are you using to run your code? `node filename.js` should work.

Comment: I am using node server.js ... And it launches, and then im able to access the server on a web browser. Its an issue with one of the modules im trying to include with the javascript.

Comment: `require` doesn't exist in the browser, can you give a [mre] that shows *where* this code is running?

Comment: Sure. The HTML file has a call to functions in its Javascript file. In the javascript I have a >> var cpaas = require('@avaya/cpaas/'); << This is where the error is being thrown. The rest of the script works fine (for HTML button controls ext.) but it won't load in these other modules for some functions I have written.

Comment: Ah right, you can't use require in the browser natively -- you need to bundle your code with a bundler such as webpack or rollup

Comment: Okay ill look into it now. Thanks for that!